# How to keep same session in Android for both web service and webviews?

Tags: android, wcf, session, authentication, android-webview

I am developing a hybrid Android application which consists of **Native** and **Webviews**. For some native data retrieval I am using **JSON** over **WCF webHttpBinding**. Both services and web pages are under same website.

I am thinking of doing authentication for webservice call by sending back(over SSL) the sessionID back to server and comparing it. But now my webservice call is creating a new session every time, I am thinking of putting in the Application variables. Is there any better way?

Here are few other questions:

1. How can I keep the session for the webviews after I have navigated
   to other activities and come back to webview.
2. Is there a way to use one connection for both web services and web
   pages?
3. How can I make a simple authentication for the webservice call for
   the current user? (I don't want to make DB call)